# Re-initializing rbenv via shell if already initialized

Tags: ruby, shell, bash

I am certain that I phrased the question wrong. So, let me explain my question and someone can edit it for me.

I am a newbie working on Jekyll and I installed rbenv. I am not sure from where I was following instructions. I have this below line in my .bash_profile:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null;
  then eval "$(rbenv init -)";
fi
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

I have no clue what it does or which language it is. Is it shell or bash or what? I am new to shell. I am was a windows user.

When I googled, I saw in other site that this is all I need:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

So, can someone please explain line by line what this code is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bash code. Since it is in the `.bash_profile` it will be executed each time a login shell is loaded.

Here is code annotated with comments that explain what each line does:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null;          # Check if command rbenv is present    
  then eval "$(rbenv init -)";       # run the rbenv initialization scripts 
                                     # and evaluate the output
fi
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" # Update the PATH variable so the ruby commands 
                                     # are available
```

The second snippet is equivalent to the first one, but it doesn't update the `PATH` variable.

Comment: Any idea what the PATH was not updated in the second snippet? What is the disadvantage?

Comment: @qbektrix: The PATH environment variable contains the directories that are searched when executing a command. Apparently in the first example the location of the ruby executables would be added. In the second example that isn't happening. It could be necessary or not depending on the versions etc...